# How to group by complex Url pattern

Tags: c#, sharepoint, linq-to-sql, group-by

I am trying to group a list of objects by its property `Url`.

For better understanding, this is the background: I have written a script, which iterates over the all `SPWebapplications` in our Sharepoint Farm and gets all permissions, on all levels down to the level of a `SPList`.
This Information is saved in this pattern:

```
Url                |    Type   |    User    |    PermLevel     |    GrantedFrom
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://farm/            SpWeb       User1          Full Control      Owner of SC
http://farm/orga        SPWeb       UserN          Read              Direct Assignment
```

And so on. 
Now as a human I know, that I have n mapped paths (`/mp1/ /mp2/` ...) which indicate this is the path to a SiteCollection. `http://farm/project/PermissionAnalysis/` would be a SiteCollection, whereas `http://farm/xyz/someList` would just be a SPList.

My goal is to group all 300.000 objects by it's SiteCollection, which needs to be parsed from it's URL.

As I said, I know, which mapped paths point to a SiteCollection, therefor I created an array:

```
var mappedPaths = new [] {"/mp1/", "/mp2/", };
```

I also know, that these mapped paths always come right after `http://farm/`
Furthermore, `http://farm/` is a Sitecollection in itself.

I can't get my head around on how to build a fitting Grouping expression in Linq to fit my requests.

The goal is to get a grouping which' keys are this:

```
http://farm/  //explicitly exclude every managed path
http://farm/mp1/
http://farm/mp2/
http://farm/mp3/
http://farm/mp4/
```

//edit:
I forgot to mention what I got so far.

```
var groupedByUrl = Permissions.ToList().GroupBy(p => p.Url.Contains(mappedPaths.FirstOrDefault()));
```

This gives me 2 Keys back. True and False, where false contains, everything, which is not a mapped path and true everything which is in a mapped path.

Comment: I'm afraid you can only do this in memory, by using `new Uri(url)` and getting selected parts of the uri.

Comment: I am currently in the process of scratching together an extension method, which determines if it is a sitecollection, or child of a sitecollection. As of now it takes in the `rootWeb` Url and a string array which contains the mapped paths. Somewhat buggy as of yet.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use default SP methods such as `SPWebApplication.Sites` to get all site collections and with that array `SPSite.AllWebs` to get all webs. No need to look at URLs and URL patterns. Also `http://farm/` - you most probably mean "web application" as the farm doesn't have a URL.

Comment: Because the code is not executed in any Sharepoint context. Let's just assume, the only source of data I have is the csv file and my knowledge of the farm architecture. And by `http://farm/` I do mean an external mapping which is in place, which also may be the url to a sitecollection.